# Issue with Flux

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux

Cannot convert from Mono to Flux

I'm getting this error while trying below code

```
public Flux<PortCall> updateByFindById(String gsisKey, PortCall portCall) {
    return portCallRepository.findAllByVesselCodeOrderBySequenceNo(portCall.getVesselCode())
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, PortCallConstants.ROUTE_NOT_FOUND)))
                .collectList().flatMap(list -> {
                    if (list.size() > 0)
                    return Mono.just(list)
                       .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
                });

}
```

Please suggest a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Using  `collectList()` and check for an empty list is redundant, because if your repository method doesn't emit any elements, it automatically calls `switchIfEmpty`operator.

Just leave it like that:

```
return portCallRepository.findAllByVesselCodeOrderBySequenceNo(portCall.getVesselCode())
            .switchIfEmpty(
                    Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, PortCallConstants.ROUTE_NOT_FOUND)));
```